# Gmail API - place a watch using a service account

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

We want to place a watch on gmail account we have been granted access to
(see also https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch).

Placing a watch requires a PUB/SUB topic name, which we have: `projects/project-name/topics/topic-name`. 
When creating this, we set the publish permissions for member `allAuthenticatedUsers` (grants access to any user signed in to a Google Account).
**This works and we are able to get watch notifications into the topic and consume the messages correctly.**

---

Now, we'd like to constraint the publishing permissions a bit more by allowing only a service account to do it.
We've created a service account (`gmail-watch@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com`), and set it as the sole publisher for the topic.
This service account was also configured with the role `Pub/Sub Publisher`
 on IAM.

Now, when making this change in the code, and trying it out, we're getting the error:

`Google::Apis::ClientError (failedPrecondition: Bad Request)`

This is the code, fwiw:

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'google/apis/gmail_v1'

scope = 'https://mail.google.com/'
authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open('./config/google-service-account.json'),
  scope: scope
)

Gmail = ::Google::Apis::GmailV1
service = Gmail::GmailService.new
service.authorization = authorizer
service.watch_user(
  'user-email@gmail.com',
  {
    topic_name: 'projects/project-name/topics/topic-name',
    label_ids: ['INBOX','SENT'],
    label_filter_action: 'include'
  },
  {}
)
```

We've tried also setting the `sub` param in the authorization:
`authorizer.sub = 'user-mail@gmail.com'` but the error is the same, although we can no longer fetch access tokens after this:

```
> authorizer.fetch_access_token!

Signet::AuthorizationError (Authorization failed.  Server message:)
{
 "error": "unauthorized_client",
 "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
}
```

What are we missing here?

Comment: Check first, if service account has permission to the API in the Google Dev Console where it was generated. Does it contain all necessary scopes?

Comment: the service account has "domain wide delegation" enabled, and the roles "Service Account Token Creator" and "Pub/Sub Publisher"

Comment: Usually when this error happens is due to a missing scope. Does it help adding "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"? You can also go to [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to test authorizations for requests.